# Expression Blend and Scatterview

Tags: wpf, expression-blend, pixelsense, scatterview

I would like to animate a ScatterView Control using Expression Blend

However, it seems that Blend doesn't recognise this control and nothing is visible on the design surface despite it being in the xaml

Is there an addon or something that you need to get Blend to recognise controls that are specific to MS Surface?

Have been googling this for ages but can't find any info on this

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created a Blend WPF project in Visual Studio (I always start that way) and opened it in vanilla Blend. Everything fine here, ScatterViewItem is being rendered and I could manipulate it. You should start from the project templates Microsoft ships for Visual Studio to have the required references being set. Have you done this that way?

Comment: thanks - that seems to work. My starting point had been one of the samples that come with the sdk